# Which condition I'm failing to satisfy in removing circular doubly linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list, structure, circular-list

This is my removing function.

```
void removeAt (int pos)
{
    struct Node *temp= (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node *)); 
    struct Node *x=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node *));

if(pos==1)
{
if(head==tail)

{ 
    temp=head;
    head=tail=NULL; 
    free (temp);
}

else
{

temp=head;
head=head->next;

head->prev=tail;
tail->next=head;

free (temp);
}
}

else
{

    temp=NULL;
    for(int i=0;i<pos;i++)
    { 
        x=temp; 
        if(i==0)
        temp=head;

        else
        temp=temp->next;
    }

    x->next=temp->next;

    if(temp==tail)
    x->next=head;
    else
    temp->next->prev=x; 
    free (temp);

}

}
```

This function gets input as position and removes an element at that position.
When I run this I'm getting private test case failed.
I can't figure out which test case I'm failed to satisfy.
Please do help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you have memory leaks.

Comment: why I will get memory leak?

Comment: As for your problem, I recommend that you pull out a pencil and some paper. Then draw a simple list using squares for nodes and arrows for the links between them. Try to solve the problem on paper first, erasing and redrawing arrows as needed, and (very important!) write down a numbered list of the actions you make. If one way fails throw the paper away and start over again. When you have a way that works then you implement it.

Comment: `struct Node *temp = malloc(...);` followed by `temp = ...`. The pointer returned by `malloc` is lost and you'll have a leak. Same with `x` (for which you don't even call `free`).

Comment: I also recommend that you build with extra warnings enabled and treat them as errors. A compiler should be able to warn you about some things you do which doesn't make sense. Like `temp-temp->next;`.

Comment: Yeah thanks, I will just declare temp and x so I can prevent them from getting memory leak.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude temp-temp->next; I can't copy or paste code in my online idle. So I used google lens to get those in text.

Comment: @YouSuggestMe Note that `struct Node *temp= (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node *));` should be `struct Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));` (your `sizeof()` was wrong), the same goes for `struct Node *x = ...`.

Comment: If you can't use such basic things like copy-paste, then your environment is flawed (in my not humble oppinion). You won't be able get far with only online environments anyway, so please find some suitable offline environment. There are a few good ones that are even free to download and use.

Comment: The memory leak comes from `temp = malloc(...); temp = head`.  You no longer have a reference to the memory that was allocated.

Comment: `temp = head; free(temp)` is the same as `free(head)`.

Comment: Side remark: is this really how you indent your code?

Comment: `head->tail`: your nodes have a `tail` member? Please include the definition of `Node`...

Comment: no head and tail are struct members(pointer members). struct have these things: data, prev,next

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some issues:

- Don't allocate memory: the function is not going to add any node, so this memory serves nothing, and will actually leak.
- `head->tail` is an invalid reference. Where you have this line, you should set `head = tail = NULL;`
- `if(temp==tail) x->next=head;` should not be needed: as your list is circular, it should always have `tail->next == head`, so this assignment is not needed.
- `temp->next->prev=x;` should *always* be executed, also when `temp == tail`. As the list is circular so the `tail` node does not need special treatment when it comes to setting `prev` or `next`.
- There is no code to adjust the `tail` reference when you have removed the `tail` node.
- As the list is circular, there should be no need to differentiate between `pos==1` and others. The special cases to pay attention to are:

  - when the list is empty, the function should not do anything.
  - when the list has just one node, it should be emptied.
  - if the `head` node is deleted, that `head` reference should be updated (as you do)
  - if the `tail` node is deleted, that `tail` reference should be updated

Here is the corrected code:

```
void removeAt(int pos) {
    // Safeguard
    if (head == NULL || pos <= 0) return;

    // Don't allocate node memory with malloc
    struct Node *temp = head;
    if (head == tail) {
        head = tail = NULL; // fix
    } else { 
        for (int i = 1; i < pos; i++) { 
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->prev->next = temp->next;
        temp->next->prev = temp->prev;
        if (temp == tail) tail = temp->prev;
        head = tail->next;  // Invariant
    }
    free(temp);
}
```

Comment: Thank you I learned many things. btw what is this "You need 15 reputation to cast vote"

Comment: Users can up or downvote posts on this site. But to avoid that accounts are registered for the sole purpose of casting some votes, there is this requirement that you must at least gain some reputation. But it is not hard to gain 15 points.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few significant problems.  First of all, since you are deleting nodes, I would expect to see `free` statements but no `malloc` statements.

Regarding lines:

```
struct Node *temp= (struct Node *) malloc(sizeof(struct Node *)); 
struct Node *x=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node *));
```

Pointers `x` and `temp` should be left uninitialized or set to `NULL`.

Under condition `if(pos==1)` / `if(head==tail)`, you only have one node, so you would basically be freeing head and setting both `head` and `tail` pointers to `NULL`.

Under condition `if(pos==1)` / `else`, your code should work as-is.

Under condition `else`, it doesn't make sense to begin the for loop at zero, since the position can never actually be zero and since this requires an extra conditional statement.  However, if `pos` were set to zero, you would be dereferencing a Null pointer, which would cause an exception.  Also, I am not sure why this condition is needed:

```
if(temp==tail)
    x->next=head;
```

Comment: No, it didn't change anything. Still, I'm facing the same issue